# Do flags expire?

Tags: support, flags

I flagged [something](https://askubuntu.com/questions/440602/changing-mozilla-26-0-for-ubuntu-themes) as off-topic. Twenty hours on, that flag is still active.

I know mods are volunteers (and so on), but I would like to know why this flag is still pending **only** if the reason isn't mod unavailable.

If there is some other reason and I am educated about it, I may not flag badly in future.

Comment: As Braiam said below, moderators don't see close flags. They go into the close vote queue and that takes a long time to go through (usually).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flags aren't handled by moderators anymore. Any flag to close a question is added to the Close queue immediately and the flag isn't marked as helpful until someone casts a close votes, or all reviewers consider to leave the question open, in which case it's marked as declined.

The review queue has a backlog and reviewers are dealing with them.

Comment: Flags are marked as "declined" only if a ♦ moderator declines it. In case the flag gets declined based on the judgement of community users (3k+, 10k+ and 20k+) it is marked as "disputed".

Answer (score 4):

There are two different types of flags that one can raise:

1. **Moderator-only flags** which can only be seen and handled by moderators.

   These age-away/expire based on guidelines given in the following question:

   - [When are moderator flags automatically dismissed as "aged away" by the system?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/204327/when-are-moderator-flags-automatically-dismissed-as-aged-away-by-the-system)
2. **Review flags** which go to their respective review-queues (low quality, close/duplicate).

   Only canonical migration flags expire. Since, Ask Ubuntu doesn't have any canonical migration target (as of now), it is irrelevant for us.

   - [Do flags to close expire like votes to close?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207179/do-flags-to-close-expire-like-votes-to-close)

Based on my experience, most of the flags get handled within a couple of hours. However, in case of Review flags it can stretch to a couple of weeks. And, in case of Moderator-only flags which might require some investigation it can stretch to a couple of days.

As to your belief that since the flag is taking time to be handled, you might have raised a bad flag — don't worry about it. If a flag is taking time to be handled, it *generally* indicates that you have raised a good flag. I would leave its interpretation upto you :-)